# Quarkus datasource with Heroku

Tags: java, heroku, heroku-postgres, quarkus

I'm trying to deploy my Quarkus-app on Heroku. It works fine, but I needed to specify the datasource-parameters with fix values. Because Heroku might rotate this parameters, this is not a really good idea.

In Quarkus, I need this 3 parameters in `application.properties`:

```
quarkus.datasource.username
quarkus.datasource.password
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url
```

Heroku only gives me 1 environment variable (`DATABASE_URL`), which defines a connection-string in the following manner:
`postgres://user:pass@server:port/db-name`

I know I can use environment variables like so:
`quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url = jdbc:${DATABASE_URL}`

But I need to split up the variable to extract user and password and to change prefix (postgresql instead of postgres).

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Hi @simon-wick did you solve your problem? If yes, please tell me how.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `JDBC_DATABASE_URL`, `JDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME` and `JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD` environment variables for your use-case.

For more details, you can find the documentation here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-relational-databases-on-heroku-with-java#using-the-jdbc_database_url

Comment: From documentation: `The official Heroku buildpacks for Java, Scala, Clojure, and Gradle will attempt to create a JDBC_DATABASE_URL environment variable when a dyno starts up.` I deploy quarkus native application (docker image) to heroku, can I some how force heroku to add  `JDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME` and `JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD` variables?

Comment: @tostao Sadly, you cannot do that. Heroku adds those JDBC environment variables with a script on dyno startup. We package that script in your slug (image) with our official JVM buildpacks.

However, since those buildpacks are open source, you can grab the script and use it in a custom docker image: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-jvm-common/blob/c972dd9148c7cf3cb3a838e0d28a095e537d8b06/opt/jdbc.sh

Comment: just that I got your point: do I need to install this `heroku-buildpack-jvm` and it will work? Or should I add this `jdbc.sh` script somewhere to my deployment job? Any example will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a bash script to extract the three Quarkus parameters from Heroku   `DATABASE_URL`.

It worked for me with JVM and Native versions.

My `application.properties`:

```
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=${DB_JDBC_URL:jdbc-url}
quarkus.datasource.username=${DB_JDBC_USER:postgres}
quarkus.datasource.password=${DB_JDBC_PASSWORD:postgres}
```

## Short version

```sh
# cut the DATABASE_URL after '@'
export DB_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://${DATABASE_URL#*@}

# substring the DATABASE_URL between '//' and ':'
export DB_JDBC_USER=$(expr $DATABASE_URL : '.*/\([^:]*\):.*')

# substring the DATABASE_URL between ':' and '@'
export DB_JDBC_PASSWORD=$(expr $DATABASE_URL : '.*:\([^@]*\)@.*')
```

## Long version

### Bash script

Save the following script with the [heroku.sh](https://gist.github.com/felipewind/a6fa978a2e96cf30cf71d2be5cfa8985) file name in the root folder of your project.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# =============================================================================
# This script automatically splits the Heroku ENV DATABASE_URL variable
# into the three JDBC variables needed from Quarkus.
# 
# It will only do the split if the DB_HEROKU_SPLIT is set to "true".
#
# If you set DB_HEROKU_SPLIT to 'false', you must pass the Quarkus parameters:
#   - DB_JDBC_URL;
#   - DB_JDBC_USER;
#   - DB_JDBC_PASSWORD.
# 
# For test purposes, you can set the DB_ECHO_VALUES to 'true' and check if the
# values are correct.
# 
# Pattern of DATABASE_URL from Heroku:
# --------------------------------------
#   postgres://username:password@host:port/databasename
# 
# Pattern of JDBC variables of Quarkus:
# -------------------------------------
#   quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://host:port/databasename
#   quarkus.datasource.username=username
#   quarkus.datasource.password=password
# 
# =============================================================================

echo DB_HEROKU_SPLIT=[$DB_HEROKU_SPLIT] 

# check for 'true' in string (case insensitive)
if [[ "${DB_HEROKU_SPLIT,,}" == "true" ]]; then

  # cut the DATABASE_URL after '@'
  export DB_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://${DATABASE_URL#*@}

  # substring the DATABASE_URL between '//' and ':'
  export DB_JDBC_USER=$(expr $DATABASE_URL : '.*/\([^:]*\):.*')

  # substring the DATABASE_URL between ':' and '@'
  export DB_JDBC_PASSWORD=$(expr $DATABASE_URL : '.*:\([^@]*\)@.*')

fi

# check for 'true' in string (case insensitive)
if [[ "${DB_ECHO_VALUES,,}" == "true" ]]; then

  echo DATABASE_URL=[$DATABASE_URL]
  echo DB_JDBC_URL=[$DB_JDBC_URL]
  echo DB_JDBC_USER=[$DB_JDBC_USER] 
  echo DB_JDBC_PASSWORD=[$DB_JDBC_PASSWORD]

fi
```

### Dockerignore

Remember to include this file into your `.dockerignore`:

```
*
!heroku.sh
!target/*-runner
!target/*-runner.jar
!target/lib/*
!target/quarkus-app/*
```

### Dockerfile.jvm

Replace the original `ENTRYPOINT` by this:

```
# commands from original Quarkus Dockerfile.jvm file suppressed for breviety

COPY --chown=1001 heroku.sh /deployments/heroku.sh
RUN chmod 540 /deployments/heroku.sh

CMD [ "/bin/bash", "-c" , ". /deployments/heroku.sh && /deployments/run-java.sh" ]
```

### Dockerfile.native

Replace the original `CMD` by this:

```
# commands from original Quarkus Dockerfile.jvm file suppressed for breviety

COPY --chown=1001 heroku.sh /work/heroku.sh
RUN chmod 540 /work/heroku.sh

CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", ". ./heroku.sh && ./application", "-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0"]
```

### Heroku Config Vars

**DB_HEROKU_SPLIT**

Add the `DB_HEROKU_SPLIT` to your Config Vars of Heroku and set it to `true` if you want the bash script to extract the Quarkus datasource variables to you.

Set it to `false` and you can create the Quarkus datasource (DB_JDBC_URL, ,DB_JDBC_PASSWORD and DB_JDBC_PASSWORD) in the Heroku Config Vars and pass them directly to Quarkus bypassing the bash script.

**DB_ECHO_VALUES**

I also create a `DB_ECHO_VALUES` variable that allow you to display the data source on the logs. If you want to print the log on the screen, just set `DB_ECHO_VALUES` to true.